# How to bypass ENTITY_IS_DELETED?

Tags: apex, soql, dml, dmlexception

I have some apex as follows

```
1: List<Culture_TCH__c> oldCultures = [SELECT Id FROM Culture_TCH__c WHERE Assessment_TCH__c = :oldAssessment.Id];

2: delete oldCultures;
```

Simple enough, but this sometimes throws an ENTITY_IS_DELETED error. Even without using ALL ROWS. How come? Is this because other code might be running at the same time and deleting the rows between lines 1 and 2?

OK so my question is how do I prevent ENTITY_IS_DELETED getting thrown in this instance? I'd like to run the delete without regard to this error, and delete all the rows it can, even if some in the list have already been deleted.

Comment: Try adding the `FOR UPDATE` clause.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Database.delete(recordToDelete, allOrNone)`.

`allOrNone` If you specify false for this parameter and a record fails, the remainder of the DML operation can still succeed. This method returns a result object that can be used to verify which records succeeded, which failed, and why.

Also use `FOR UPDATE` clause in SOQL query as mentioned by **sfdcfox** and **Adrian**

Comment: @sfdcfox, yes FOR UPDATE to be mentioned in SOQL query

Answer (score 2):

You might look at using the `FOR UPDATE` clause. See [Locking Statements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm):

> In Apex, you can use FOR UPDATE to lock sObject records while they’re being updated in order to prevent race conditions and other thread safety problems.
>
> While an sObject record is locked, no other client or user is allowed to make updates either through code or the Salesforce user interface. The client locking the records can perform logic on the records and make updates with the guarantee that the locked records won’t be changed by another client during the lock period. The lock gets released when the transaction completes.