# Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id xxxxxxxxxx; first error: ENTITY_IS_DELETED, entity is deleted: []

Tags: trigger, data-loader, list, future

I am trying to Upsert bulk records in Custom object using dataloder. I got error like:

> FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id xxxxxxxxxx; first error: ENTITY_IS_DELETED, entity is deleted: []

in FutureHandler Operation time.

how to prevent this error in bulkrecords upsert time. in my csv file i didnt insert lookup fields also.

Comment: i am using externalid field @RohitMourya

Comment: External id is present in object ?

Comment: Yes, External id is present NITHESH K

Comment: Then did you mentioned external id while importing in data loader

Comment: yes, mentioned @NITHESHK

Comment: get ids and  try to get records in  query editor , whether the result is comes or not ?

Comment: Still not then you have to share the more details forunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Double check your field mappings to make sure the ID column in your CSV field is properly mapped to the Salesforce field.   Second, make sure you are importing into the right Salesforce org.  This is a pretty common cause of problems if you take a CSV export from Production and try to import into the Sandbox (or the other way around).  Last, you can copy/paste one of the IDs from the CSV file into your Salesforce browser URL (after the salesforce.com/ part) to see if that ID really does display a record.

Answer (score 0):

SEKHAR: You can use Database.delete(recordToDelete, allOrNone).

allOrNone If you specify false (Database.delete(recordToDelete, false)) for this parameter and a record fails, the remainder of the DML operation can still succeed. This method returns a result object that can be used to verify which records succeeded, which failed, and why.

FYI: [How to bypass ENTITY_IS_DELETED?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/134150/how-to-bypass-entity-is-deleted)

Comment: Question related to inserting bulk records using dataloder, Not using Apex code.